# How can I query for the yaml filepath for all pipelines in our dev azure project?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to list all the yaml files in use in any devops pipeline. I can do:

```
az pipelines show --project ProjectName --query '{pipeline:name,repo:repository.name,yml:process.yamlFilename}' --output table --name PipelineName
```

and get the right result:

```
Pipeline       Repo           Yml
-------------  -------------  ---------------------------------------
PipelineName   RepoName       path/to/azure-pipeline.yaml
```

but if I `list` instead of `show` -- I want all of them, not one at a time -- `list` doesn't return the same level of detail. It doesn't give me repository and process data, so I can't list the repo name or the yaml path.

How can I get repo name and yaml path for *all* my pipelines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get repo name and yaml path for all your pipeline, you could use REST API to [list all your pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0), and [get each pipeline details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0), then, according to result to [get repository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/get-repository?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP). Finally, generate a file with pipeline name, repository name and path. Here is the PowerShell script for the whole process. Please replace with your own PAT, organization name, project name and the path you want to store the file. Here set the **path=null** for classic pipeline.

```
$PAT ="<PAT>"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($PAT)"))
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic $base64AuthInfo")
$response = Invoke-RestMethod "https://dev.azure.com/<orgName>/<ProjectName>/_apis/pipelines?api-version=6.0-preview.1" -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers
$response | ConvertTo-Json   

foreach ($value in $response.value)
  {
  $mid=$value.id
  $url = "https://dev.azure.com/<orgName>/<ProjectName>/_apis/pipelines/"+$mid+"?api-version=7.1-preview.1"
  $pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod $url -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers
  $pipeline | ConvertTo-Json
  $pipelinename = $pipeline.name
  if ($pipeline.configuration.path)
    {
    $path=$pipeline.configuration.path
    $repositoryid=$pipeline.configuration.repository.id
    $url = "https://dev.azure.com/<orgName>/<ProjectName>/_apis/git/repositories/"+$repositoryid+"?api-version=6.0"
    $repositorydetails = Invoke-RestMethod $url -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers
    $repositorydetails | ConvertTo-Json
    $repositoryName=$repositorydetails.name
    }
  else
   {
   $path="null"
   $repositoryname=$pipeline.configuration.designerJson.repository.name
   }
   Write-Output "$pipelinename, $repositoryName, $path" >> C:\workspace1\new1\test.txt
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. So I guess there is no alternative to iterating over the pipelines and querying for each one?

Comment: Hi @Chris F Carroll, it's the only way to list all the pipelines with repository name and YAML path that you want. If you want to simply list all you pipelines, please use the REST API I have mentioned above. If it helps, just a remind of [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).